# Form Submit Using actionFunction in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction, form

I want to submit my complete list of opportunities using `<apex:actionfunction/>`
but in the code behind I am not getting any updated values, also I want to submit attachment and notes in the list of opportunities But unable to do so as well.

Comment: Could we see your code ? Please focus this question on a single issue. What have you done to debug this so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Updated values first using getter and setter methods and update those values using actionFunction.

Please see the below example:

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="saveRecords" action="{!SaveOpps}" rerender="list"/>

<apex:commandButton onclick="saveRecords()" value= "Save"/>

<apex:PageBlock id="list">

   <apex:PageBlockTable value ="{!listOpps}" var="o">

     <apex:column value ="{!o.Name}"/>

   </apex:PageBlockTable>

</apex:PageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
public List<Opportunity> listOpps {get;set;}

public void SaveOpps(){
update listOpps ;

}
```